# Set date as the value for a workbook defined name?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have VBA write a value to the Name manager to store a date instead of using the `Today()` function in formulas.

I have this code that seems to work. 
`ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Today", "=Datevalue(""" & Date & """)"`

Is there a better way to do this? Without using `DATEVALUE()`?

Comment: Personally I'd use `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "Today", Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any place Today() is used, a strictly numerical value should be able to be used in its place.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="Today", refersto:=chr(61) & CLng(Date)
```

That should do. It seems redundant to change Date to a text value only to turn around and convert it to a date again with DateValue.

You may not want the defined name visible to others.

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:="Today", refersto:=chr(61) & CLng(Date), visible:=false
```

I would recommend placing this in the Workbook_Open or other appropriate sub procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Names("Today").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Today", RefersTo:=Chr(61) & CLng(Date), Visible:=False
End Sub
```